# React Native NavigationEvents: onDidFocus getting Infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am using [NavigationEvents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) to load my list automatically.

So far it does work and it loads my updated list but on the console it keeps running the API call function on INFINITE LOOP.

However, whenever I open list screen, I just want to load the API call function ONCE.

So if there is any better solution please feel free to help.

**Code snippet below:**

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

import NameActionBar from '../components/mNameActionBar';
import FreelancerList from '../components/mFreelancerList';

export default class MasterScreen extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getFreelancerList();
        console.log('ComponentDidMount()');
    }

    getFreelancerList() {
        console.log('Freelancer List');
        let self = this;
        AsyncStorage.getItem('my_token').then((keyValue) => {
            console.log('Master Screen (keyValue): ', keyValue); //Display key value
            axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: Constants.API_URL + 'user_m/freelancer_list/',
                responseType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'X-API-KEY': Constants.API_KEY,
                    'Authorization': keyValue,
                },
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    //console.log('Response Data: ', response.data.data);
                    console.log('Response: ', response);
                    self.setState({
                        dataSource: response.data.data,
                    });
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('Error: ', error);
                });
        }, (error) => {
            console.log('error error!', error) //Display error
        });
    }

    viewFreelancerList() {
        const { dataSource } = this.state;
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={dataSource}
                    keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <FreelancerList {...item} />}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {<NavigationEvents onDidFocus={this.getFreelancerList()} />}
                <NameActionBar />
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.viewFreelancerList()}
                </ScrollView>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to define callback function which are going to invoke on some event. Either you have to **bind** the function in constructer or make that function as **arrow function**.
A best practice is to never use an arrow function in a class property; it harms testability and limits what the engine can optimize. 
Using bind will attach the methods to class prototype.

> this. getFreelancerList = this. getFreelancerList.bind(this)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I added bind to my constructor, reverted the arrow function and tested again. Your solution also solved my issue and gives just what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

You need to remove the parentheses when you pass the method to onDidFocus. Make it look like this: `onDidFocus={this.getFreelancerList}`

This is a common gotcha with react. When you include the parentheses after the function name, you are actually executing the function. Based on your code, it looks like that isn't actually your intention. You are trying to pass a callback to onDidFocus, so that when, and only when, the component receives focus, the method is called.

The reason you're experiencing the infinite loop is that you are updating state in getFreelancerList. So your component renders, and you immediately call `getFreelancerList`. In `getFreelancerList`, you are updating state, causing the component to render yet again. Then, you guessed it, as the component rerenders, it calls `getFreelancerList` again, and the cycle repeats :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and the explanation. Removed the parentheses and also changed the function **from** `getFreelancerList(){ ... }` **to** `getFreelancerList = () => { ... }`.